# automatic/programatic opt-in for new QSB/Search Manager content provider

Tags: android, android-qsb

I wrote a new Content Provider to serve a new Searchable Item class for the Search Manager.

As I understand now, user has to opt-in so that my new searchable item class is included in their global search.

Is there a way to automatically opt-in when my app is installed?  Or to do this programmatically so that I can provide a dialog box where user can opt-in through my app easily?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to automatically opt-in when my app is installed?

No.

> Or to do this programmatically so that I can provide a dialog box where user can opt-in through my app easily?

No. However, you can try to invoke [`ACTION_SEARCH_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SEARCH_SETTINGS) to start up the search page of the Settings app, where the user can check the checkbox.